# Left Align Badges

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I have created this card here [image: Picture] in which i have some badges but they are not aligned in the right way i need to left align them like this image.[image]. Can anyone help me in aligning these badges just like they are aligned in the second image? I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 and this just a little code snippet and i think this is enough information.

here is the html code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="card main-content">
    <div class="row clearfix" id="line">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="header">
          <h2>
            Insights
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="display: table;">
              <div>
                Total Students
                <span class="badge badge-primary">
                                            0
                                        </span>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div>
                Subjects
                <span class="badge badge-primary">
                                            20
                                        </span>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div>
                Sections
                <span class="badge badge-primary">
                                            289
                                        </span>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div>
                Created On
                <span class="badge">
                                            27/8/2018
                                        </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I converted your example into snippet and the issue is not present. That means that there's something in your own styles floating the badges to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your labels in a `<span>` tag and give it a [`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width). This way, the badges will be horizontally left aligned and vertically on the same line:

```css
.insight-label {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="card main-content">
    <div class="row clearfix" id="line">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="header">
          <h2>Insights</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="display: table;">
              <div>
                <span class="insight-label">Total Students</span>
                <span class="badge badge-primary">0</span>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div>
                <span class="insight-label">Subjects</span>
                <span class="badge badge-primary">20</span>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div>
                <span class="insight-label">Sections</span>
                <span class="badge badge-primary">289</span>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div>
                <span class="insight-label">Created On</span>
                <span class="badge">27/8/2018</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```